# Execute the else statement if none of the items are found

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement, for-loop

I have this for loop, and I would like to execute the else in the for loop only if none of the if conditions are met. The for loop runs until every item in the database has been checked. If none of the items in the database matches the user input then I want to run the else.

Right now, it runs the else right after the first try which means if the item matches is in the last row, it will just throw it in the error page since it stops the evaluation at the first iteration.

```
for(var i=0; i< rows.length; i++) {

  if (rows[i].hashtag == userEnteredHashtag) {
    // Display the choose Box page
    res.render('chooseBox', {});
  }


  else {
    // Display the invalid hashtag page
    res.render('invalidHashtag', {});
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just check the database for a match directly ?

Comment: True, but I was running into some issues, and for some security reason i felt this was better option

Comment: anywho `rows.every( o => { return o.hashtag !== userEnteredHashtag});`

Comment: Thanks. Could you kindly elaborate that has answer?

Comment: A little bit shortly: `rows.every(o => o.hashtag !== userEnteredHashtag);`. `rows` is a `Array` and has method `every`. This method test each row by condition. `o => smthCond` is arrow function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just move the `else` portion outside of the loop and execute it based on a flag

```
var wasFound = false;
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

   if (rows[i].hashtag == userEnteredHashtag) {
     // ...
     wasFound = true; // set the flag here
   }
 }

if (!wasFound) {
  res.render('invalidHashtag', {});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So add a check outside.

```
var hasMatch = false;
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

  if (rows[i].hashtag == userEnteredHashtag) {
    // Display the choose Box page
    res.render('chooseBox', {});
    hasMatch = true;
  }
}

if (!hasMatch) {
  // Display the invalid hashtag page
  res.render('invalidHashtag', {});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable to track whether your condition has been met:

```
    var isValid = true;
    for(var i=0; i< rows.length; i++) {
      if (rows[i].hashtag != userEnteredHashtag) {
        isValid = false
      }
    }
    isValid ? res.render('chooseBox') : res.render('invalidHashtag')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
var rows = [{hashtag: '#a'}, {hashtag: 'b'}, {hashtag: 'c'}];
var userEnteredHashTag = '#a';
var matchingRows = rows.filter(row => row.hashtag === userEnteredHashTag);

if (matchingRows.length) {
  matchingRows.forEach(row => console.log(row)); 
} else { 
  console.log('invalid'); 
}
```